# Laravel's save() does not save all fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

AdvertiseController.php

```
class AdvertiseController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function NewAdvertiser()
    {
        $advertiser = new Advertiser((string)Uuid::generate(4));
        $advertiser->createAdvertiser();
        return Redirect::route('dashboard');
    }
    ...
}
```

Advertiser.php

```
class Advertiser extends Model
{
    ...
    protected $fillable = ['token'];

    private $token;

    function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    function createAdvertiser()
    {
        //dd($this);
        $this->save();
        //dd($this);
    }
    ...
}
```

The first `dd($this)` prints the following:

```
Advertiser {#181 ▼
  #fillable: array:1 [▼
    0 => "token"
  ]
  -token: "44f1e74b-ad19-4e73-ac2e-b37ffde59e99"
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

The second `dd($this)`:

```
Advertiser {#181 ▼
  #fillable: array:1 [▼
    0 => "token"
  ]
  -token: "295764d5-c45c-4aa9-8ce2-8ed772687fb8"
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:3 [▼
    "updated_at" => "2016-05-19 11:39:42"
    "created_at" => "2016-05-19 11:39:42"
    "id" => 7
  ]
  #original: array:3 [▼
    "updated_at" => "2016-05-19 11:39:42"
    "created_at" => "2016-05-19 11:39:42"
    "id" => 7
  ]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
}
```

The `token` has a minus sign, does it have anything to do with it? I couldn't find any information about it.

The database migration for the field:

```
$table->uuid('token');
```

The problem is that all the records are stored successfully but the `token` field is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems with your model. You only need the fillable property populated. Remove the constructor as it removes eloquents ability to populate your models correctly which is causing you the problems. There is no need to wrap the save method either. Also making token a property of the class is not the way to make it an attribute of the model. To answer your question about the `-` sign, that is because it was declared as a private property.

This is an example of how your model should look.

```
class Advertiser extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['token'];
}
```

If you really must override the constructor you should make sure it constructs the parent with an array of attributes.

```
class Advertiser extends Model
{
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

In this case your controller would need to look something like the following.

```
class AdvertiseController extends Controller
{
    public function NewAdvertiser()
    {
        // Create the model with an attributes array
        $advertiser = new Advertiser([
            'token' => (string)Uuid::generate(4)
        ]);

        // Save the model
        $advertiser->save();

        return Redirect::route('dashboard');
    }
}
```